# How to customize Firebase Auth domain on Android

Tags: java, android, firebase, oauth-2.0, firebase-authentication

Does someone know how to customize the Auth domain for Firebase Auth UI Library? I want to change from x.firebase.io to my custom domain auth.example.com. I am using Microsoft login and It wants me to use an app like Chrome to sign in but in the url you can use is firebase.io that I want to change. I have got it working with Javascript, there you only need to change the Auth domain directly in the config section but how can you do the same on Android? or is that not even possible or does someone have a good solution for it? I Have searched around a lot but only found how to do that for javascript pages.

I am building an app for Android in Java.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The most common option on Android is to use a private URI scheme and redirect URI in your app, and to point to a remote authorization server.

Maybe have a look at the [Android AppAuth Sample](https://authguidance.com/2018/02/20/android-setup) as something to compare against, and try reconfiguring it for your scenario.